# Large gap below HTML5 video on mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

For some reason (and only on mobile devices) a large gap is appearing after this video on my page http://scott.ewarena.com/blog - the big gap only appears on mobile devices.

Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Scott

CSS:

```
            /* Video CSS */
            .homepage-hero-module {
                border-right: none;
                border-left: none;
                position: relative;
                width: auto;
                height: 400px;
            }
            .no-video .video-container video,
            .touch .video-container video {
                display: none;
            }
            .no-video .video-container .poster,
            .touch .video-container .poster {
                display: block !important;
            }
            .video-container {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0%;
                left: 0%;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;

            .video-container .poster img {
                width: 100%;
                bottom: 0;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .video-container .filter {
                /*z-index: 100;*/
                position: absolute;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                width: 100%;
            }
            .video-container video {
                position: absolute;
                /*z-index: 0;*/
                /*bottom: 0;*/
            }
            .video-container video.fillWidth {
                width: 100%;
                }

            #video_overlays {
            position:absolute;
            float:left;
                width:100%;
                height:400px;
                background-color:transparent;
                z-index:1;
            }
```

HTML:

```
                <!-- Video test -->

                    <div id="video_overlays">

                    <div class="abovethefold">
                        <h1 class="blog-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
                        <?php $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' ); ?>
                        <?php if($description) { ?><p class="blog-description"><?php echo $description ?></p><?php } ?>

                            <p class="button">
                    <a class="blue-button" href="#cta">Let's work together</a></p>
                    </div></div>


                <div class="homepage-hero-module">
                    <div class="video-container">
                        <div class="filter"></div>
                        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
                            <source src="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/MP4/Busy-People.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
                            <source src="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/WEBM/Busy-People.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
                            <img src="http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/Snapshot/Busy-People.jpg" title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag">
                            </video>
                                                    <div class="poster hidden">
                            <img src="http://scott.ewarena.com//blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/Busy-People/Snapshots/Busy-People.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I know this isn't much help but videos on mobile look unsightly due to the play button and no auto playing on IOS. Could this lead to just replacing the video with an image for small devices?

Comment: reduce the height of `.homepage-hero-module` on mobile

Comment: Thank you @MichaelCoker , that worked a treat!

Win I know, there's a way to make an image appear in its place on Mobile devices but I haven't got around to working that out yet! :)

Comment: I found the answer, which is to add the following CSS:

     *::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
       display: none!important;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
     }

     *::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {
       display: none!important;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
     }

     *::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
       display: none!important;
       -webkit-appearance: none;
     }

Answer (score 0):

Try making `.homepage-hero-module` height `35vh`

```
.homepage-hero-module {
  height: 35vh; /* 35% of viewport height */
}
```